# How to regenerate xmlsitemap to https?

Tags: xml-sitemap

I'm new to Drupal community and I wonder if there is a solution to regenerate all urls from http to https?

I have already tried to just regenerate and try to update `$base_url` in setting, nothing helped.

Answer (score 3):

There is a setting in the XMLSitemap admin configuration that lets you set the base domain. Update that value, clear cache, and regenerate the sitemap.

Comment: Base url is set to https, but not working anyways

Comment: `$base_url` or the one in the admin configuration? If both are set to https, there is something else that is getting in the way then.

Comment: Both are set to https, what else it should be?

Comment: Within our deployment workflows, we're setting this (state API) value to the current environment's base URL, rebuild caches and run cron (using Drush) to rebuild the xmlsitemap. It always works.